# precise scaling of matlab textboxes with axes magnification

Tags: matlab

I would like to have a text box rescale with the level of magnification, such that one unit of text is always assigned one unit of horizontal axis-length. The text width should not change but rather the spacing between characters.

For instance, if the x-axis displayed `[0:50]`, fifty characters should be displayed, one at each integer position. If the magnification was increased such that the display comprised only `[0:10]`, only ten characters would be displayed, again placing one character at each integer position along the horizontal axis.

Finally, the text would ideally not display when the magnification level was below some threshold determined by the number of characters that can be legibly printed along a horizontal line spanning the extent of the axes.

I have tried using the `text` object, but it doesn't seem to have the relevant properties to allow such dynamic behavior. I have instead considered breaking the `N`-length string into `N` unit-length strings and placing each at a defined x-position, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to display only those relevant at the prevailing zoom level (there is some spill-over of characters beyond the bounds of the axis).   In contrast, with this approach, all the characters appear as a jumble at zoom levels so low that the number of characters printed cannot be reasonably accommodated.

Thus, I inquire whether another solution besides printing a series of unit-length strings might be advised and, if not, how the twin problems of text spill-over and text overlap can be resolved at high and low zoom, respectively (the first might be done by somehow preventing printing of information outside the axes; the second seems to require some dynamic magnification-aware means of suppressing text output at or above a certain x-axis extent).

Comment: Printing each character at its own position (e.g., `for i=1:length(string) text(offset+i,height,string(i); end`) is, for the most part, satisfactory, and seems to be the most general solution. The problem of text "spillover" beyond the bounds of the axes can be neatly solved by enabling the `Clipping` property of the text object during declaration (`text(x,y,char,'Clipping','On')`). However, I still look for a solution to suppress display of any text at magnifications low enough that the text becomes an incomprehensible jumble. Presumably, the solution will depend on a magnification-aware ...

Comment: ... listener that suppresses output upon zooming or figure resizing if the product of the number of characters (current extent of x-axis) and the width per character divided by the extent of the x-axis on the screen exceeds a predetermined threshold, and restores output when zoom/resize operations bring the value below that threshold. The one problem with the idea of printing each character in its own text box is that the rendering becomes quite slow for any significant length of axis (e.g., 5000 units), which is why the magnification-dependent suppression system would be helpful.

Comment: The [zoom](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html) post-callback function appears to be the relevant solution to the problem of magnification-aware text display. The solution will be quite simple, involving an initial statement that deletes all text previously created through explicit calls to the post-callback function, followed by a conditional printing of text, subject to evaluation of the current x-axis extent compared to the width of a character printed at the given font size (which will be most facile for a monospace font).