# matlab zoom callback error associated with text function

Tags: matlab

While trying to execute generation of a series of text boxes in a post-zoom callback function in Matlab, a number of errors are generated, the trace of which is unhelpful in diagnosing and resolving the problem. When the text generation is in the main body of code as follows, the code executes properly and there is no issue executing the minimal post-zoom callback function:

```
string='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
offset=8;
h=figure;
z=zoom(h);
set(z,'ActionPostCallback',@post_callback);
[ax,plt1,plt2]=plotyy(14:20,1:7,15:17,1:3,@bar,@bar)
ylim([0 10]);
hold on;
set(plt2,'FaceColor','r');
xLim=xlim(gca);
for i=xLim(1)+1:xLim(2)-1
    text(i,8,string(i-offset+1),'Clipping','on');
end



function post_callback(obj,evd)
    xLim = get(evd.Axes,'XLim');
```

However, if the text box generation is moved to the `@post_callback` function, a series of errors result:

```
string='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
offset=8;
h=figure;
z=zoom(h);
set(z,'ActionPostCallback',@post_callback);
[ax,plt1,plt2]=plotyy(14:20,1:7,15:17,1:3,@bar,@bar)
ylim([0 10]);
hold on;
set(plt2,'FaceColor','r');



function post_callback(obj,evd)
xLim = get(evd.Axes,'XLim');
for i=xLim(1)+1:xLim(2)-1
    text(i,8,string(i-offset+1),'Clipping','on');
end
```

Those errors are, as described in [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25111369/873757):

```
Warning: An error occurred during the mode callback. 
  > In uitools.uimode.fireActionPostCallback at 14
  In zoom>local2DButtonUpFcn at 1332
  In hgfeval at 63
  In uitools.uimode.modeWindowButtonUpFcn at 46
  In uitools.uimode.setCallbackFcn>localModeWindowButtonUpFcn at 58
```

Could someone please enlighten me as to the root cause of the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be the same. You should try to use the [debugger](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) here. Set a breakpoint in your post callback function. However, there are a few problems in your code. Some are implementation issues, some other problems does not do what you ask them too. You seems to have some programming experience, so I guess that most implementation issue are just bugs. I will list problems and solutions.

1) I cry when I see that you use string as a variable. String is an abstract type (obselete in matlab now since later versions uses `char` vectors). use instead some other name like `str` or `myString`.

2) Unless `offset` and your variable `string` is not declared global, they will not be inside the scope of `post_callback`. Different from C or C++, a variable does not become global when defined in "main" (since you do not even define a main method). If you want to use `string` or `offset` inside of `post_callback`, you must define them inside their scope (inside the function).

3) the loop variable `i` must not be a cell. Use the method from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111369/matlab-zoom-callback-error-associated-with-plotyy-function/25114055?noredirect=1#comment39085489_25114055) to convert it to a double vector.

4) The loop variable `i` must be an integer in:

```
text(i,8,string(i-offset+1),'Clipping','on');
```

since string is defined a variable and variable indices must be integers, `xLim` does not necessary need to be an integer.

5) I do not think `text` will give the expected output here. What `text` does is creating a string and linking it to a point on the plot. This means that every time you zoom you will have a new text in the plot. Unless the texts are located at exactly the same place (which may be possible, but will reqire a lot of work) the plot will look really ugly. If possible, place the `text` strings in the way that you do in example 1 and remove it from `post_callback`.

Comment: (0) Thanks for pointing out the debugger. I wasn't familiar with it, since I write most of my code in `vi`. (1) Of course, I would never call a variable `string` in a real script, and only used the term for explanatory purposes in the sample code posted here : ) (2) You make a good point about the variable scope. I suppose I assumed global scope by default, so I'll pass as an argument to the call-back function instead. (3) About the `cell` type, I don't think I fully appreciated this point from your answer to the last question, as I could have sworn that my output from the `xlim` command ...

Comment: ... was `double` rather than `cell`, but I'll be sure to check this again when I return to the computer on the script is executed. I noticed in my actual code that when the limits were large (e.g., 3.05 * 10^5), I had to use awkward typecasting like `xLim=double(uint32(xlim(gca)))` to force the variable to be a double in non-scientific notational format (I suppose a `sprintf` would have worked as well) because the `for` loop iteration and string indexing required either `int` or `double`, and the text positioning required `double` type. I find it odd that the `xlim` command would give ...

Comment: ... cell rather than numerical output. (5) I realize that the use of a text function in the zoom callback function must appear strange. The goal here is to place text at a defined location only when the zoom level is high enough to distinguish individual characters (as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25096212/873757)). What I have neglected to include in the sample code here is a function that first deletes any text that was drawn from previous zoom operations, to avoid the ugly overlap problem you have described. Therefore, I plan to have an `if` statement check the ...

Comment: ... magnification, and optionally generate text boxes at defined locations if the magnification is above some predefined threshold. In all cases, the pre-existing text will be deleted through calls to the relevant object handle destructors.

Comment: @user001 **Warning! do do on modify the input to a callback function. The argument list is predefined in matlab gui. Instead, add them as fields to the figure struct. Then they can be read and written to through the `set` and `get` functions.** Regarding (3), the output from `xlim` is only a cell if there are more than 1 `axis` pretty stupid, but matlab can be like this sometimes. You need an `if iscell(myXLim)` statement. (5) If you absolutely need to use `text`, then make sure that the text string appear in the right locations and try to find a way to delete the handles when changing zoom

Comment: @user001 handles to the `text` objects I mean.

Comment: Hi patrik. Can you tell me what you mean by adding arguments as fields to the "figure struct"? I searched a bit for "figure struct" but came up empty. Thanks

Comment: @user001 Sorry, I rather mean the `handles` argument of course. That should be the third argument in the callback function. Set [mathworks help](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)